# sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: PRODUCTOSS

Tags: python, base-de-datos, sqlite3

Estoy siguiendo un curso de Python , de Píldoras Informáticas , pero me sale un error. Aquí esta la parte del error:

```
#cursor.execute("INSERT INTO PRODUCTOSS VALUES('PELOTA',15,'DEPORTES')")
    
    varios=[
        
        ("Camiseta",10,"Deportes"),
        ("Computadora",10000,"Computacion"),
        ("Jarron",432,"Ceramica"),
        ("Libro Elige tu Propia Aventura",210,"Literatura"),
        ("Camisa",445,"Deportes"),
        ("Kerbal Space Program",10000,"Videojuegos"),
    
    ]
    
    cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO PRODUCTOSS VALUES (?,?,?)", varios)
                                                                             
    coneccion.commit()                                                       
                                                                             
    coneccion.close()
```

En la linea "INSERT INTO PRODUCTOSS" me salta el error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: PRODUCTOSS
```

Intenté usar la librería "os" pero no funcionó.

Espero que tenga solución. Gracias.

Comment: Qué error te da? Por favor agrégalo a la pregunta (como texto). Para editar tu pregunta haz click en [edit]. Tambien te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y leas [ask] y [example]. Saludos!

Comment: gracias ya te pongo

Comment: Por favor, primero lee los artículos que te compartí. Te prometo que no te tomará más de 5 minutos. [tour], [ask] y [example]

Comment: Seguro que no estas escribiendo mal la tabla? Porque estas poniendo doble `s` al final de PRODUCTOS... Revisa, tu estas con `PRODUCTOSS`, no es `PRODUCTOS`??

Comment: @AndresGardiol Gracias

Comment: @AlfaRojo no, porque pose productos, y me salto un error, así que puse productoss, remplasando la tabla en todo el codigo

Comment: Solo revisa que la tabla existe y que este bien escrito el nombre m, por que el error dice que la tabla no existe

Comment: @Christian ya lo verifique antes y existe, solo en esa parte que puse no existe

Comment: Abre tu editor de sqlite (DB Browser, SQLiteStudio, dbVisualizer, etc...), conecta a la base de datos en cuestión, y ejecuta la consulta: `SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';` Copia los registros del resultado y pégalos en la pregunta.

Comment: @aeportugal a que te referís con pegarlo en la pregunta?

Comment: oh..... el archivo que contenía la tabla lo puse en otra carpeta.... no la misma en la que esta el programa.... de ahí el error

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasaba es que tenia el programa en la carpeta BBDD, y dentro tenia la carpeta Archivos, donde guardaba los archivo que me creaba, entonces hay estaba el problema... tenían que estar en la misma carpeta.